Есть ли классы официальные для C++ CLR 2008 для вычисления солнца восхода и заката (sunrise and sunset)?
Перепробовал 5 разных классов с интернета, и всех баги, при прогоне в цикле например 44 дней (соклько на экран в MsgBox влазит). "Как будто без сверки с PHP опубликовали в интернет"). Результаты отличаются от того же теста в PHP, который совпадает с повседневностью.

Уж не помню, откуда я взял это, но у меня с официальными данными расхождение в минуту-другую :)
